# Spring (for Android) and Jackson2: PUT as application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: java, android, json, spring, spring-android

I am somewhat new to HTTP REST operations on Android, and a server I am working with uses PUT commands to process updates. I am having a difficult time using Spring (for Android) with Jackson2. The server doesn't seem to work with `application/json` put requests (though it will reply with them), and only seem to work with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` versions (tested with python and curl. On python, if I set the header type to `application/json`, it fails.

I am using the latest versions of Spring and Jackson2, and I know everything is setup properly because my get request on the same URL gets me all the correct information.

I am using Robospice, but I don't really think that is relevant. Here is my request code.

```
@Override
public GPIO loadDataFromNetwork() throws Exception {
    String url = String.format("http://%s/api/control/gpio", ip);
    RestTemplate rt = getRestTemplate();
    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    Credentials defaultcreds = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("admin",
            password);

    client.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
            new AuthScope(routerip, 80, AuthScope.ANY_REALM), defaultcreds);
    // Makes authentication work.
    rt.setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(client));
    HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders(); 
    requestHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);

    HttpEntity request = new HttpEntity(data, requestHeaders);
    List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter map = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    messageConverters.add(map);
    messageConverters.add(new FormHttpMessageConverter());
    rt.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);

    ResponseEntity<GPIO> r = rt.exchange(url, HttpMethod.PUT, request, GPIO.class);
    return r.getBody();
}
```

I am getting the exception stating it cannot find a way to convert:

```
02-01 10:59:29.466: E//DefaultRequestRunner.java:138(30086): 
10:59:29.474 Thread-11651 An exception occurred during request network 
execution :Could not write request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter 
found for request type [com.xxxxx.control.gpio.GPIO] and content 
type [application/x-www-form-urlencoded]
```

GPIO is my POJO object. I want to 'put' that to the server, as in serialize and put it.

I have looked at the following question that seems fairly relevant:

- [Deserializing Nested objects using RestTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14491309/deserializing-nested-objects-using-resttemplate?rq=1)

However, I need the result of my put command, and that requires me to use `exchange()` because Spring's `put()` returns nothing.

I have tried several different items (such as removing GPIO references, setting specific headres...) and none seem to work. I have a feeling this is probably an easy solution that I don't know how to fix. If anyone can help me that would be great.

TLDR: I'm using Spring for Android with Jackson2. I want to serialize my object (in this example, GPIO) so I can do a PUT request with the content type application/x-www-form-urlencoded. However I cannot get jackson to convert to that type, only to application/json, which does not work for me. I am not sure how to fix this, and I have run out of ideas. If I can't find a solution I'll probably have to dumb robospice. (or jackson, not sure which yet.)

**Solution**

Spring for Android doesn't seem to simplify things, so I dumped it and used the apache client directly in my loadDataFromNetwork() method. Robospice handles it pretty well and I can get the responses I need. If you are new to HTTP like I was take the time and learn the apache client, it's far easier in my opinion. Tweaking the ObjectMapper (like making a JsonTree and parsing that) made it much easier to get the data I needed without having to do as much work with POJO objects.

Comment: You may want to have a look at [`FormHttpMessageConverter`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-android/blob/master/spring-android-rest-template/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/converter/FormHttpMessageConverter.java) as I believe it doesn't know of your `GPIO` class

Comment: I've added that to the types of converters but I'm not sure how to get it to see my class. I have many classes that will likely need to be serialized as my API is fairly large.

Comment: Can you share the client (javascript/jquery, etc.) code that calls the method?  I was having a similar problem that required a specific format for encoding the request body.

Comment: Uh... I don't have access to the source code of the server (if that's what you are asking). I can ask the people who own it but it seems to reject application/json puts.

Comment: It's located here: https://github.com/Mgamerz/RouterAPIShowcase/blob/MobileMapper/src/com/cs481/mobilemapper/responses/control/gpio/PutRequest.java It doesn't use jquery/javascript though.

Comment: I redact my last edit - sorry, I thought this was an issue on the server side.  Spring+Jackson2 made me think it was a server-side issue.

Comment: I edited the post to make it a bit clearer.

Comment: Have you tried Retrofit (https://github.com/square/retrofit)? This is really easy to do using Retrofit.

Comment: I think I might just dump spring. They advertise as convenient but don't even make a convenience method for put responses like they do for the others...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can format the data you want to send into `MultiValueMap<String, String>`, then a possible way around this is to use `FormHttpMessageConverter`.

[FormHttpMessageConverter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-android/docs/1.0.1.RELEASE/api/): (you can see examples in the link)

> An HttpMessageConverter implementation that can read and write form
>   data from the HTTP request and response. By default, this converter
>   reads and writes the media type application/x-www-form-urlencoded.
>   Form data is read from and written into a `MultiValueMap<String,String>`.

Comment: Ubfortunately I cannot. It is wrapped in encapsulating elements which made this not work. I spent 2 days on this... Gave up on that route.

Comment: Did you try setSupportedMediaTypes on the MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter  with "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" ? ( you need to build an array of mediatypes) I'm using that when receiving weird contenttypes maybe it will work the other way around?

Comment: Tried that. My data must have a data=params format and this doesn't do that unfortunately. The params must be UTF8 but the data= part should not be.

Comment: I know. I forgot to update the question. The people I am working for asked me to make it private unfortunately.

Comment: Can you post the POJO?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47183/discussion-between-raanan-and-mgamerz)

Comment: Where I am at (work) the SO chat is blocked so I can't use that right now. I'm going to award you the bounty for helping me with this though. I'll reply in the chat when I can.

Comment: Can you test serializing your POJO using ObjectMapper writeValueAsString ?

Answer (score 0):

After re-reading, here's a shot at a real answer - you are explicitly using the `x-www-form-urlencoded` content type by using this `RequestHeader`:

```
HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders(); 
requestHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
```

You should be using `APPLICATION_JSON` - [Here's the Javadoc](http://jackson.codehaus.org/javadoc/jax-rs/1.0/javax/ws/rs/core/MediaType.html#APPLICATION_JSON).

You should also consider specifying the charset and datatype in the headers.  Jaxson is *very* specific about this, and if you don't have access to the server code you don't know what headers they expect.

Comment: The server does not accept application/json - I tested with python. Curl and Python by default send as x-www-form-urlencoded type. (I also used Wireshark and confirmed this). If I set the type in python to application/json (it does indeed send the proper JSON object), the server responds with an exception. (exception: 'key'). However it works with x-www-form-urlencoded. The server takes `x-www-form-urlencoded` and respond with a `JSON` object. (That's standard Jquery from what I've heard, apparently.)

Comment: @Mgamerz this is the exact issue I'm also facing, still searching for help

Answer (score 0):

dude i am using Loopj's AsyncHttpClient for rest and json dataset.
Here is the link below [Here](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/doc/com/loopj/android/http/AsyncHttpClient.html)

Very simple and easy to understand. U can try this thing.

Comment: This doesn't really integrate into robospice however, and AsyncTask's are bad when you have rotation of the device (which is why I am using robospice).