# Map Nested JSON Objects to Java Classes with Spring RestTemplate

Tags: java, json, spring, resttemplate

I know this may be simple. However, I just can't get it to work.

So I am trying to use Spring RestTemplate to map my JSON data. I have following JSON response from a rest call.

```
{
  "message":"ok",
  "status":"ok",
  "data":[
      {"Name":"Yo",
       "Address":"100 Test Rd"},
      {...},
      {...}
   ]
}
```

And here is the class I am trying to map it to.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Response implements Serializable {

  private String message;
  private String status;
  private List<Data> data;

  // I could also use a array instead
  // private Data[] data;
}
```

Here is my Data class:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Data implements Serializable {

  private String Name;
  private String Address;
}
```

Here is the code I used to call RestTemplate:

```
public Reponse getResponse() {
    ResponseEntity<Reponse> responseEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity(Url, Reponse.class);

    return responseEntity.getBody();
}
```

Now here comes the problem. I was able to get "message" and "status", But when I try to log/print data, it shows null. Not exactly sure what's going on here. I really could use some help. Thanks.

Comment: i'm having the same issue did you find a solution for this?

Comment: DId you find any solution? thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I was having a similar issue with RestTemplate not mapping nested JSON objects to my class model also, after much frustration I decided to retrieve my JSON as a String(instead of converting directly to my target object) using RestTemplate and then use the google Gson library to convert my String to my target entity.

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

code to call RestTemplate:

```
 ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity(Url,String.class);
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
Response reponse = gson.fromJson(responseEntity , Response.class);
```

Unfortunately I was unable to find out why my nested objects were not mapped using RestTemplate the first place but I hope this workaround helps!

Comment: I removed the nested class and created another class

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue when reading Json data from REST API using Rest Template. To resolve declare getters and setters for the List:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Response implements Serializable {

  private String message;
  private String status;
  private List<Data> data;

 // getters and Setters for the list. 


}
```

The RestTemplate will internally map the values from the listarray to the corresponding array.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue. Annotate with `@JsonProperty`:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Data implements Serializable {

    @JsonProperty("Name")
    private String name;

    @JsonProperty("Address")
    private String address;

    // getters / setters for name and address

}
```

The fields of your `Data` class should now get populated, and you can name your fields independent of the JSON representation (e.g. `name` instead of `Name`).

Answer (score 1):

Annotate property "data" with @JsonUnwrapped as below

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Response implements Serializable {
    private String message;
    private String status;
    @JsonUnwrapped
    private List<Data> data;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread.

But for anyone having the same problem, you can use `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` for this purpose with Jackson.

Please refer the answer given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14491309/deserializing-nested-objects-using-resttemplate) thread.

Answer (score 1):

Change this

> `private String message; private String status; private List<Data> data;`

To This

> `public String message; public String status; public List<Data> data;`

That worked for me !

Answer (score 0):

Please use `private List<Data> data = new AllarList<Data>( )`;
and please provide getters( ) and setters( ) methods in both the classes.

Put `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY)` above Data class

Please add below dependencies under   section at your main POM.xml file and do maven compile. Then I guess your issue will get resolved.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-joda</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.8</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: I didn't put up setters and getters here to avoid messes. Tried to initialize "data". Still returns null. Also compile error on "Include.NON_EMPTY", "Include cannot be resolved to a variable"? Thanks.

Comment: please import this : import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;

Answer (score -1):

If you need only print data, you can do this

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(
    "your url",
    String.class);

System.out.println(response);
```