# How can I use Spring RestTemplate to map nested data to beans where the top-level is a variable?

Tags: json, spring-boot, jackson, resttemplate

I have some JSON data like the following.  I see other solutions using a bean as a wrapper to the inner nodes, but in this data, the top-level string is not a named parameter ("TSLA" and "LVS" below).

I'd like to use Spring RestTemplate and return instances of `Equity` beans that contain getters and setters for each property using Lombok.

```
{
  "TSLA": {
    "assetType": "EQUITY",
    "assetMainType": "EQUITY",
    "cusip": "88160R101",
    "symbol": "TSLA",
    "description": "Tesla, Inc.  - Common Stock",
    "bidPrice": 1001.88,
    "bidSize": 100,
    "bidId": "Q",
    "askPrice": 1002.17,
    "askSize": 100,
    "askId": "B",
    "lastPrice": 1001.88
  },
  "LVS": {
    "assetType": "EQUITY",
    "assetMainType": "EQUITY",
    "cusip": "517834107",
    "symbol": "LVS",
    "description": "Las Vegas Sands Corp. Common Stock",
    "bidPrice": 48.33,
    "bidSize": 200,
    "bidId": "P",
    "askPrice": 48.34,
    "askSize": 300,
    "askId": "P",
    "lastPrice": 48.33
  }
}
```

Here is my code.  `json.getBody()` returns null and I get an NPE.

```
public Optional<List<Equity>> getQuotes(final String... tickers) {

//redacted the URL string creation.  I get the correct data with the URL.

    try {
        final ResponseEntity<JsonNode> json = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, JsonNode.class);
        List<Equity> equities = new ArrayList<>(tickers.length);

        for (String ticker : tickers) {
            Equity equity = mapper.readValue(Objects.requireNonNull(json.getBody()).get(ticker).toString(),
                    Equity.class);
            equities.add(equity);
        }
        return Optional.of(equities);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Could not retrieve quote for " + Arrays.toString(tickers), e);
    }
    return Optional.empty();
}
```

I tried using [Jackson2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14491309/deserializing-nested-objects-using-resttemplate), but it had no effect.  I know the mapping is off with this code, but I don't see how to correct it with Spring.

Answer (score 0):

After some exploration, I found a solution that doesn't use the RestTemplate, but uses the Jackson API.  It reads the tree and creates the objects using the values from each node.

```
public Optional<List<Equity>> getQuotes(final String... tickers) {
    //URL creation redacted

    try {
        JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(new URL(url));
        List<Equity> equities = new ArrayList<>(tickers.length);

        for (String ticker : tickers) {
            JsonNode topLevel = node.path(ticker);
            Equity equity = mapper.treeToValue(topLevel, Equity.class);
            equities.add(equity);
        }
        return Optional.of(equities);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Could not retrieve quote for " + Arrays.toString(tickers), e);
    }
    return Optional.empty();
}
```